# How to work with async server calls in Reactjs 16.7.0

Tags: reactjs, async-await

What is the correct way to use async methods as props in ReactJs? I have an app which mounts a component "dashboard" and this component then loads two drop down menus. The first drop down is populated by async `fetch` at the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

When the first drop down changes, the async event handler is triggered and the state property `selectedAId` is supposed to be set. If I debug this in the browser I do see this state prop set. After the state is set, the same event handler also calls an async server method to get some data based on the state property `selectedAId`.

If I then go to the async server method `getEntitledSites`, the parameter sent to the method is "0", instead of the value that I previously saw being set in the event handler.

Here is the gist to a summary of the code:

https://gist.github.com/thehme/c4b5a958ef1a6e5248f697375c9cb84b#file-api-ts-L15

**api.ts**

```
class Api {
...

async getEntitledForA() {
    try {
        const orgsResponse = await fetch('/api/v1/orgs');
        const orgResponseJson = await orgsResponse.json();
        return orgResponseJson.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
}

async getEntitledSites(orgId: number) {
    try {
        const sitesResponse = await fetch('/api/v1/study/' + orgId + '/sites');
        const sitesResponseJson = await sitesResponse.json();
        return sitesResponseJson;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
}
}

export default new Api();
```

**dashboard.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SelectDropDownA from '../components/SelectDropDownA';
import SelectDropDownB from '../components/SelectDropDownB';
import SelectDropDownC from '../components/SelectDropDownC';

class CreateDashboard extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            organizations: [],
            sites: [],
            selectedAId: "0",
            selectedBId: "0",
            selectedCId: "0",
            showBMenu: false
        }

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let organizations = await Api.getEntitledForA();
        this.setState({ organizations });
    }

    async onSelectedOrgChange(selectedOrgId) {
        if (selectedOrgId !== 0) { 
            this.setState({ selectedAId });
            let sitesData = await Api.getEntitledSites(this.state.selectedAId);
            this.setState({ 
                sites: sitesData.sites,
                showSitesMenu: true
            });
        }
    }

    ...


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel">
                <div className="insidePanel">
                    <SelectStudyDropDown 
                        onChange={e => this.onSelectedOrgChange(e.target.value)}
                        ...
                    />
                </div>
                {this.showSitesMenu && 
                    <div className="insidePanel">
                        <SelectSiteDropDown
                            onChange={e => this.onSelectedSiteChange(e.target.value)}
                            ...
                        />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CreateDashboard;
```

I am wondering if this has to do with how I am using `async/await` or the binding of the `onChange` method.

**SOLUTION:** In my particular case, I do not need `this.state` to set `selectedAId` before starting my server request, so by passing the parameter straight to the request, works fine. Then I can simply move the setting of `selectedAId` to the second instance of `this.setState`. This would not work, if I needed `selectedAId` to be set before making the server request, in which case, I would have to wait for `this.state` to finish being set, but this isn't the case since I want my server request to start right away.

```
async onSelectedOrgChange(selectedOrgId) {
    if (selectedOrgId !== 0) { 
        let sitesData = await Api.getEntitledSites(selectedOrgId);
        this.setState({ 
            selectedAId,
            sites: sitesData.sites,
            showSitesMenu: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the code is a bit long and a pain to format sometimes, but please include it into the question rather than using a gist. It's important for questions to be clear and referenceable in the future and not relying on an external resource. :)

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` is asynchronous and not awaitable (i.e. does not return a promise), so if you want to do something with the new state after it has been set, you need to do it in a callback:

```
this.setState({ selectedAId }, async () => {
    let sitesData = await Api.getEntitledSites(this.state.selectedAId);
    this.setState({ 
        sites: sitesData.sites,
        showSitesMenu: true
    });
});
```

---

Additionally, in your example, `onSelectedOrgChange` isn't binded to `this` anywhere. However if this was an issue the whole thing would have broken long before so I suppose that you just left it out by accident?

---

Furthermore I would advise you to extract the `e.target.value` inside the handler and pass `onChange={this.onSelectedOrgChange}` as the prop, because in your current code you're creating a new `onChange` handler every time render is called.

Comment: humm, idk about the binding part, I've actually created and anonymous function for the `onChange` props, which automatically bind `this`, and therefore, the constructor `.bind()` is not needed.